# 3 dimensional array definition in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tried following method but it seems not working, if not using numpy, what is the right way? Thanks.

```
x = [[0]*3 for _ in range (3) for _ in range(3)]
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's making a two dimensional `list` where the outer dimension is `3 ** 2` in length. You need nested `list` comprehensions to make it three dimensional, just add a couple extra brackets to what you have:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> x = [[[0]*3 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
>>> pprint.pprint(x)
[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger, vote up and mark your reply as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a comprehension instead of `[0]*3`:

```
size = 3

[[0 for i in range(size)] for i in range(size)]
```